# Implicit assumption behind the definition of scalar, vector, and tensor fields

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, vectors, covariance

Let me consider a field
\begin{align}
A^\mu(x) \equiv dx^\mu,
\end{align}
which seems to be a vector field trivially.
However, to check that, we calculate as
\begin{align}
A'^\mu(x') \equiv dx'^\mu = \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\rho}dx^\rho = \frac{\partial x'^\mu}{\partial x^\rho}A^\rho(x).
\end{align}
Note that $A'^\mu(x') = dx'^\mu$ is not derived in some way, but **defined**.

**Question**:
Can't we distinguish types of field with only its specific coordinate-representation (in the above example, $A^\mu(x) = dx^\mu$)?

Let me introduce another example.
We may forget the above definition and define a **scalar** field $a^{(0)}(x)$ by
\begin{align}
a'^{(0)}(x') = a^{(0)}(x) \equiv A^{0}(x).
\end{align}
If defined so, the functional form of $a'^{(0)}(x')$ is given by
\begin{align}
a'^{0}(x') = a^{(0)}(x(x')). 
\end{align}
If we define $x'^\mu=f^\mu(x)$, then
\begin{align}
a'^{0}(x') = a^{(0)}(x(x')) = d((f^{-1})^{0}(x'))= \frac{\partial (f^{-1})^{0}(x')}{\partial x'}dx'^{\mu} \neq A'^0(x') =   \frac{\partial f^0(x)}{\partial x^\rho}A^\rho(x).
\end{align}
It looks that we obtained a new scalar field in a consistent way, with the coordinate-representation which does not seem to be a scalar.

I think the origin of problem is an implicit assumption on a (scalar/vector/tensor) field on a manifold, which is independent of coordinates.

Comment: I think the confusion comes because you are trying to define the concept of "field" within a mathematical formalism. "In physics, a field is a physical quantity, represented by a scalar, vector, or tensor, that has a value for each point in space and time" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics) . on which , scalars vectors or tensors one follows the formulae of the mathematical model built to represent physical quantities and predict their future behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. First, you call the question a confusion, but I rather just suggest that there is no unique way to define a transformation rule without the assumption I mentioned. In physical context, such possibility is important in an energy momentum tensor density of a massive particle in GR. There, mass density (includes a 3d delta function) will be treated as a scalar because tensor indices come from ${dx^\mu/d\tau} {dx^\nu/d\tau}$, while the 3d delta function is naturally not a scalar.

Comment: In other words, my quenstion is related how do we define 'prime' on a transformed field? It seems not to be equivalent to just substituting x' = Λx in SR.

Comment: We do not need to define vectors by "how they transform under coordinate changes", this is really an artefact of skipping a differential geometry class in order to arrive at something usable in physics more quickly. The factors you multiply vectors (and more generally tensors) by to arrive at their "transformation rules" come from the definition of the pushforward and pullback operations on the various vector/tensor spaces. If you're troubled by the typical wording in physics books I'd recommend picking up a good textbook on differential geometry and satisfying yourself about it that way.

Comment: @Charlie Yes. Thus, I think the assumption mentioned is for a corresponding function on a manifold $M$. For example, the definition $A'^\mu(x') \equiv dx'^\mu$ is indeed giving a definition for $A: p \in M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$. Mathematically, the definition of such $A$ comes at first, and $A'^\mu$ and $A^\mu$ should be derived by specifying the pullbacks. In physics literature, I think $A$ on $M$ is implicitly defined through the definition $A'^\mu(x') \equiv dx'^\mu$. Is it correct discussion?

Comment: $dx^\mu$ is not a vector *field* but a vector. It represents a difference between two manifold points when those points are infinitesimally close. Thus it is an element of tangent space of a specific point.

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. The vector $dx^\mu$ is just an example, so please read my question with appropriate replacements.